# Softlayer python client upgrade

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We are using softlayer-python-4.1.1 and when we invoke self.ordering_manager.get_package_by_key(package_keyname), we will get the exception "('OrderingManager' object has no attribute 'get_package_by_key')". Is this because we are using a dated version of our client?  And is the new client version backward compatible with our existing code?

Comment: How would we know if the newer module will work in your code base? Do your unit tests still pass after upgrading the module version?

Answer (score 0):

the error is because the version that you are using 4.1.1 does not have that method, it has the methods:

```
    def get_package_id_by_type(self, package_type):
        """Return the package ID of a Product Package with a given type.

   def get_package_by_type(self, package_type, mask=None):
        """Get a single package of a given type.

  def get_packages_of_type(self, package_types, mask=None):
        """Get packages that match a certain type.
```

So if you want to use the method `get_package_by_key`you need to upgrade the client.

Comment: Is the new version of the client backward compatible with our current code base?

Comment: I cannot assert that all your code are going to still working, but you should always use the last versión of the client because the API is always changig and the new versions of client hace been made to support those changes